# Verificar se determinadas partes de uma planilha possuem dados

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu tenho uma planilha que tem duas partes e quero verificar se ambas possuem dados.

Se a **Parte 1** e a **Parte 2** possuírem dados, o código pinta a linha correspondente de amarelo.

Caso apenas umas das partes possuírem dados, o código não faz nada.

**Problema:**

Se a **Parte 1** tem dados e a **parte 2** não tem, ele funciona.

Se ambas as partes tem, ele também funciona pintando de amarelo.

Agora, se apenas a **parte 2** tem dados, ele pinta de amarelo mesmo assim.

**Este é meu código:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Plan1")

Dim i, j, largura, linha As Integer
Dim parte1, parte2 As Boolean

parte1 = False
parte2 = False
largura = 22
linha = 2

For i = 2 To 40
   parte1 = False
   parte2 = False
   For j = 11 To largura 'Conta do 11 até 22 (Referência a posição da coluna)

        'verifica as colunas da Parte 1
        If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
            parte1 = True
        End If

        If j > 16 Then 'Inicia a verificação das colunas referentes a Parte 2
            If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                parte2 = True
            End If
        End If

        'Verifica se ambas as partes possuem dados, se sim, pinta a linha toda de amarelo
        If parte1 = True Then
            If parte2 = True Then
                 ws.Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End If

   Next j
 Next i

 End Sub
```

**Este é o resultado desse código:**[image: Como eu não quero]

**Esse é o resultado que eu queria:**

[image: Como eu quero]

Algo lógico nesse código está errado, mas não consigo ver.

Comment: Suas condicionais estão erradas, verifique seus `Ifs`. Se estão verificando as colunas corretas. Percorra seu código passo a passo com a tecla F8 e verificará o que ocorre no seu código...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que resolve com

```
    Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Plan1")

Dim i, j, largura, linha As Integer
Dim parte1, parte2 As Boolean

parte1 = False
parte2 = False
largura = 22
linha = 1

For i = 1 To 40
   parte1 = False
   parte2 = False
   For j = 11 To largura 'Conta do 11 até 22 (Referência a posição da coluna)

        If j < 17 Then
              If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                parte1 = True
            End If
        End If

        If j > 16 Then 'Inicia a verificação das colunas referentes a Parte 2
            If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                parte2 = True
            End If
        End If

        'Verifica se ambas as partes possuem dados, se sim, pinta a linha toda de amarelo
        If parte1 = True Then
            If parte2 = True Then
                 ws.Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End If

   Next j
 Next i
End Sub
```

pois não estava sendo limitado o primeiro if

Comment: Fui testando e notei uma coisa, agora a parte 2, mesmo vazia, a linha é selecionada

Comment: Da a mesma coisa, só que ao contrario.

Comment: mas vc manteve o seu if j>16??? pq aqui parece estar funcionando...

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode usar o **for each**, da seguinte forma:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim sh2 As Worksheet: Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Dim val As Boolean: val = False

Set rng = sh1.Range("A1:A20")

For Each cell In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And _
       Not IsEmpty(sh2.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value) Then
        val = True
        sh1.Rows(cell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 255, 63)
        sh2.Rows(cell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 255, 63)
    End If
    val = False
Next

End Sub
```

Esse é apenas um exemplo de como pode ser feito.

Nota: não consegui ver a imagem com o título "como seria".